# dns: empty response into my guest (specific domains)

Tags: networking, dns

In my host (windows) I'm able to get ip behind my domain:

```
> nslookup.exe setools.t-systems.es
Servidor:  clients-susu1.dns.telekom.de
Address:  10.199.135.102

Respuesta no autoritativa:
Nombre:  setools.t-systems.es
Address:  10.49.89.9
```

Into my guest (archlinux) I'm trying to get access to my service, but as you can see, I'm getting an empty response:

```
$ dig setools.t-systems.es
; <<>> DiG 9.18.21 <<>> setools.t-systems.es
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 54338
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 65494
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;setools.t-systems.es.      IN  A

;; Query time: 3 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.53#53(127.0.0.53) (UDP)
;; WHEN: Thu Jan 25 14:33:28 CET 2024
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 49
```

Using `dog`:

```
$ dog setools.t-systems.es -J
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "additionals": [],
      "answers": [
        {
          "address": "10.49.89.9",
          "class": "IN",
          "name": "setools.t-systems.es.",
          "ttl": 27,
          "type": "A"
        }
      ],
      "authorities": [],
      "queries": [
        {
          "class": "IN",
          "name": "setools.t-systems.es.",
          "type": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

However, it's also to get ip from `api.ocpdes.t-systems.es`:

```
$ dog api.ocpdes.t-systems.es -J
{
  "responses": [
    {
      "additionals": [],
      "answers": [
        {
          "address": "10.49.99.166",
          "class": "IN",
          "name": "api.ocpdes.t-systems.es.",
          "ttl": 331,
          "type": "A"
        }
      ],
      "authorities": [],
      "queries": [
        {
          "class": "IN",
          "name": "api.ocpdes.t-systems.es.",
          "type": 1
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

My `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# This is /run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf managed by man:systemd-resolved(8).
# Do not edit.
#
# This file might be symlinked as /etc/resolv.conf. If you're looking at
# /etc/resolv.conf and seeing this text, you have followed the symlink.
#
# This is a dynamic resolv.conf file for connecting local clients to the
# internal DNS stub resolver of systemd-resolved. This file lists all
# configured search domains.
#
# Run "resolvectl status" to see details about the uplink DNS servers
# currently in use.
#
# Third party programs should typically not access this file directly, but only
# through the symlink at /etc/resolv.conf. To manage man:resolv.conf(5) in a
# different way, replace this symlink by a static file or a different symlink.
#
# See man:systemd-resolved.service(8) for details about the supported modes of
# operation for /etc/resolv.conf.

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search lan lan\044tse.ads.t-systems.es
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

You just need real dns servers for the linux side. 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 are google's. They're pretty easy to configure. There's a resolv.conf in /var. Delete that. It will spawn again, because it's a socket. That will probably pick up you isp dns. `$ locate -A var resolv.conf` will find it for you.

Comment: not a socket; and also, won't magically figure out the ISP's resolver address; how is that supposed to happen? The VM does not get its configuration from the router. Also, deleting the resolv.conf (which is in /etc, not in /var) is what us experts usually call a "bad idea".